# ionic ngResource returning nothing

Tags: angularjs, rest, httpresponse, ionic-framework

I am trying to simply connect to valves API using a an example endpoint they have on their documentation. The following is the two different ways I have tried to get the data.

```
.controller('APICtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
     var svc = $resource('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json');
     $scope.data = svc.query(function(){
         console.log(svc);
     });
     console.log(svc);
})
```

And here is the more basic attempt without ngResource

```
.controller('APICtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    // Simple GET request example :
    $http.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data, status, headers, config);
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log(data, status, headers, JSON.stringify(config));
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });
})
```

Now the first one simply outputs [] as if nothing is there, the second outputs [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z6W8.png)

Note! that this url works on a browser! http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json

**Edit** So after giving up for the night I rand build for android without livereload to mess around on the app before going to bed and noticed that as soon as I did that everything started working, is there a way to enable livereload with http.get or resource?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell the [Steam API does not support CORS](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.steampowered.com%2FISteamNews%2FGetNewsForApp%2Fv0002%2F%3Fappid%3D440%26count%3D3%26maxlength%3D300%26format%3Djson&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote). I don't know a *whole* lot about Ionic, but I think this is an issue if you're developing in a browser. I don't think it's an issue if you're running on the device but don't quote me on that.

Lucky for you the folks at Ionic have solved this problem. [This post](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) really covers everything. The idea is that you need to use the Ionic CLI proxy.

In this example it should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api/steam",
      "proxyUrl": "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamNews/GetNewsForApp/v0002/?appid=440&count=3&maxlength=300&format=json"
    }
  ]
}
```

With those settings you should be able to hit http://localhost:8100/api/steam and it should work.

Comment: Based on this and other reading I think this is exactly what I am looking for. However where do I set this up? in my controller? The link you sent said inside the 'ionic.project' folder and I am new and not sure where that is.

Comment: That goes in the `ionic.project` file - I'm thinking this is at the root of your project. http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/ Covered in the "The Ionic CLI proxy server" section.

Comment: So I have copied his example and everything works just not with the steam api. Whenever I get no errors I get 400 bad response error. I know its a lot to ask but is it possible for someone else to try the steam URL I provided? I wonder if they are doing something special.